# .ajax, what goes in the success option?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am building an MVC, and I am attempting my first ajax call.  All it does is send an int to the controller Action Method, which saves some data to the DB, then returns a 'successfully saved' view.  I know the action method works, as I had an ActionLink sending the id with a Get, and all was good.  Now I need to switch it to a Post, and ActionLinks dont do Post.  So I am trying ajax.

Here is my ajax:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button-save").click(function () {
        var applicantId = $("#PersonModel_ApplicantID").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '<%: Url.Action("SaveRecord") %>',
            data: { 'id': applicantId },
            type: "post"
        });
    });
});
```

I know this part of it works, but I need to have a 'success' option, because now the 'Successful save' page is not displaying.  I have looked at some different tutorials, and to be honest the success thing confuses me.  The Action Method is all set to deliver the needed message:

```
        }
        else
        {
            return View("Error_RecordExists");
        }

        return View(model);
```

So I am wondering if there is a way to tell ajax (once it has sent the ID, to get out of the way, or something.  Thanks.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ and see for `success` property

Answer (score 1):

The success part is a function which is called when the Ajax completes successfully. It will have a number of things passed in as parameters by jQuery including the response.

The definition of the function is ...

```
Function( PlainObject data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )
```

So you would do...

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $("#SomeResultDiv").html(data); //Put the response in the div with Id "SomeResultDiv"
    }
});
```

The `data` object contains the response as a string.

The `textStatus` is pretty self-explanatory. Textual description of the Http Status for the request.

`jqXHR` is the jQuery XmlHttpRequest object - which is a wrapper around the XmlHttpRequests used in each browser. It provides information like headers, http response codes, etc... See the documentation for more information.

You can omit parameters from the end of the list if you don't want them so

```
    success: function(data) {...}
```

is perfectly valid.

Note that you can use `$.json()` instead of `$.ajax()` to call a web method which returns a Json object. These are really handy when your server doesn't know about formatting. Eg you've got a server which just reports statistics as a JSON object. Your Javascript can load that data and then create divs/graphs/etc as required. Giving you nice clean code server-side, seperation of concerns (data vs formatting) and lots of other goodness.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a simple mail sending code sample  with used webmethod

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static int SendMail(string Name, string FromEmail, string Body)
{
    StringBuilder sbBody = new StringBuilder();
    string ToEmail = "goldramesh.cool@gmail.com";
    sbBody.Append(Name + ",");
    sbBody.Append("<br/>");
    sbBody.Append("<br/>");
    sbBody.Append(Body);
    Contact contact = new Contact();
    //string script = "alert('Message sent successfully');window.location ='Contact.aspx';";
    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage eMail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
    eMail.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(FromEmail);
    eMail.To.Add(ToEmail);
    eMail.Subject = "Contact from  " + FromEmail;
    eMail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    eMail.Body = Body;
    SmtpClient SMTP = new SmtpClient();
    SMTP.Send(eMail);
    eMail.Dispose();
    contact.Clear();
    return 1;
}
```

and Ajax coding is

```
var pageUrl = 'Contact.aspx';
        $.ajax({
            url: pageUrl + '/SendMail',
            type: "POST",
            data: '{Name: "' + Name + '",FromEmail: "' + FromEmail + '",Body: "' + Body + '"}',
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            **success: function (data) {// Success 
                if (data.d == 1) {//Check success code** 
                    $("input[type=button]").val("Send Mail");
                    alert("Mail successfully sent");                     
                }
            }
        });
```

My web method is return  1. So I was checked the data.d==1

You can see my sample way's......

Comment: Note that you're not correctly escaping the data you're passing in - eg what if Name contains a comma? better would be: `data: JSON.Stringify({Name: Name, FromEmail: FromEmail, etc...})`

Comment: Yes . i am correct . Why do you use JSON.Stringify????

My sample code was working correct to me .

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/ - You're using the "traditional" parameter serialisation but you're doing it using string concatenation. Say your `Name` field was `Something with a " inside`, you data would be ... '{Name: "Something with a " inside", FromEmail: "abc@def.com" ...`. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ and http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/